# SpringBoot: How to send and access HashMap <String,String> passed through a RestTemplate HttpGet Request?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to SpringBoot and trying to figure out few things. I am sending HashMap as a part of the RestTemplate HttpMethod.GET call. My question, **Is the way I am sending the HashMap as part of the request is correct and if so how do we access the HashMap values from the MicroService2?**

**MicroService 1**

```
Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("name", "abc");

HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> entity=new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        
restTemplate.exchange("http:localhost:8080/getdata", HttpMethod.GET, entity , Object.class);
```

Now how to get the values of the HashMap passed from the MicroService 1.

**MicroService 2**

```
@GetMapping("/getdata")
Object getData(@RequestParam HashMap<String,String> user){

   sysout(user) // Null

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested below solution on my machine and its working. You need to pass information in query params as shown in below example:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.add("headerName", "headerValue");

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(header);

UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:8080/getdata");

//add data as a query params
uriComponentsBuilder.queryParam("name", "abc");

restTemplate.exchange(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity , Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct. In controller method you should pass `Map` interface instead of `HashMap` implementation, also you should use the same approach when you declare variables I mean:
`Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>()` instead of `HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();`